# php Weeknumber in selectbox with yearnumber

Tags: javascript, php, html

i need a select-menu (dropdown) with weeknumber 1 up to now + 10 weeks.
So i did:

```
                <select name="weeknummer" id="weeknummer">
                <?php
                    for ($x = 1; $x <= 52; $x++) {
                        echo '<option value="'.$x.'" >week '.$x.'</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
```

But then i get weeknumber 1 up to 52.
What i want is weeknumber 1-2018 and then the script needs to check the current weeknumber and add 10 weeks.

For example, today the selectbox should be:

1-2018,
2-2018,
3-2018,
4-2018,
5-2018,
6-2018,
7-2018,
8-2018,
9-2018,
10-2018,
11-2018,
12-2018,
13-2018

Next week it should be:

1-2018,
2-2018,
3-2018,
4-2018,
5-2018,
6-2018,
7-2018,
8-2018,
9-2018,
10-2018,
11-2018,
12-2018,
13-2018,
14-2018 << this one added

But how can i do that? Can someone help me?

Comment: `52` should be replaced with `date('W') + 10`. But beware of overflowing weeks in a year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you asked for:

```
// Get the last week of the current year. 52 or 53.
// 28 December is always in the last week of its year. (ISO-8601)
$dt = new DateTime('December 28th');
$lastWeekOfYear = $dt->format("W");

// Get the last week in the dropdown.
$lastWeek = (date("W") + 10);

// Echo all weeks from 1 to this week plus 10 (including overflowing year boundary).
for ($x = 0; $x < $lastWeek; $x++) {
    if ($x == $lastWeekOfYear) $dt->modify("1 years");
    echo '<option value="'. $dt->format("Y") . "-" . (($x % $lastWeekOfYear) + 1) . '" >week ' . $dt->format("Y") . "-" . (($x % $lastWeekOfYear) + 1) .'</option>' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i'm looking for. But how can i add the right year in the value, because it can have overflowing year boundary also?

Answer (score 0):

Like Sani Singh said in his comment
Think you are looking for something like this

```
<select name="weeknummer" id="weeknummer">
<?php
    $maxweek = (new DateTime())->format('W') + 10;
    for ($x = 1; $x <= $maxweek && $x <= 52; $x++) {
        echo '<option value="'.$x.'" >'.$x.'-2018</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

However this does not allow you to go over into the next year. and uses hardcoded year `2018` 
if you wish to have more flexibility you can use `DateTime::modify()`
forexample like this

```
<select name="weeknummer" id="weeknummer">
<?php
    $dt = new DateTime('January 4th'); //starting point - first week of year
    $maxdt = new DateTime('+10 weeks'); //ending point - today plus 10 weeks

    while ($dt->format('YW') <= $maxdt->format('YW')) {
        echo '<option value="'.$dt->format('W').'">'.$dt->format('W').'-'.$dt->format('Y').'</option>';
        $dt->modify('+1 week');
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

and you can use `intval()` to remove trailing zero from week if you wish
`intval($dt->format('W'))`

Comment: First day of january can be week number 53. Januray 4 should *always* belong to the first week of the year.

Answer (score -1):

do you mean this one?

```
<select name="weeknummer" id="weeknummer">
<?php
    $year = date('Y');
    $thisweek = intval(date('W'));
    for ($x = 1; $x <= $thisweek; $x++) {
        echo '<option value="'.$x.'" >'.$x.'-'.$year.'</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```